# How to include inside my theme an entire folder with SCSS files inside?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-architect

I've a really big project with Sencha Architect.

To work in team we need to update our SCSS theme files inside an external folder (always inside the project workspace, but outside SA).

I tried to import with SCSS inside project my external files using imports, but I need to import the entire folder instead of single files, and sencha CMD doesn't allow to use the classic * import.

Looking to the theming sencha guide, it seems that in the app.json I can set my external scss files to be processed inside the theme during the build.

```
"sass": {
  "namespace": "FocusWebModern",
  "generated": {
     "var": "sass/save.scss",
     "src": "sass/save"
  },
  "etc": [
     "sass/etc/all.scss"
  ],
  "var": [
     "sass/var/all.scss",
     "sass/var"
  ],
  "src": [
     "sass/src",
     "${app.dir}/bludataSCSS/Focus.scss"
  ]},
```

This code allowed me to import the Focus.scss file inside my theme, but using directly the folder path, the process did't work anymore:

```
"sass": {
  "namespace": "FocusWebModern",
  "generated": {
     "var": "sass/save.scss",
     "src": "sass/save"
  },
  "etc": [
     "sass/etc/all.scss"
  ],
  "var": [
     "sass/var/all.scss",
     "sass/var"
  ],
  "src": [
     "sass/src",
     "${app.dir}/bludataSCSS"//NOT WORKING
  ]},
```

So I tried also to use my build.xml file to write inside a single scss file all the imports to the other files:

```
<target name="-before-sass">
    <echo file="${app.dir}/bludataSCSS/Focus.scss" append="false">
    </echo>

    <fileset id="filesref" dir="${app.dir}/bludataSCSS" includes="*"/>
    <property name="files" refid="filesref"/>

    <echo message="Files:${line.separator}" />
    <for list="${files}" delimiter=";" param="file" >
        <sequential>
            <echo message="    @{file}"/>
            <if>
             <equals arg1="@{file}" arg2="Focus.scss" />
             <then>
             </then>
             <else>
               <echo message="Import del file: @{file}"/>
                <echo file="${app.dir}/bludataSCSS/Focus.scss" append="true">
                    @import '@{file}';
                </echo>
             </else>
            </if>
        </sequential>
    </for>

</target>
```

With this code the result file of Focus.scss is a file with the imports of all the single files inside the folder bludataSCSS.

In this case Sencha detects the changes to the file Focus.scss and stop the build process.

So the questions are:

1. there is a way to include scss files on sass compiling with the build.xml?
2. there is a way to avoid sencha CMD to detect file changes during the build?
3. there is a way to import an entire folder on the app.json sass configuration?

All your ideas will be appreciated.